# React useEffect causing infinite re-render despite passing argument to dependency array

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, render

The 'myPosts' has an object with multiple posts inside it.. I wanted the user profile to immediately show the post after it is uploaded so I passed 'myposts' in the dependency array.

But the problem is that the component is re-rendering infinitely. How can I make it so that it re-renders once, only when a new post is uploaded? I can't understand why passing 'myposts' in the array is causing infinite renders instead of only once.

```
  const [myposts, setPosts] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
  fetch('/mypost', {
    headers: {
     cookie: 'access_key',
    },
   })
     .then((res) => res.json())
     .then((data) => {
     // console.log(data);
     setPosts(data.myposts);
  });
 }, [myposts]);
```

Comment: React uses `Object.is()` to determine if a dependency has changed and `Object.is({}, {}) => false`. Even if it's the same posts are being returned from your request, the fact that you fetch a new object means your `useEffect` dependency changed.

Answer (score 1):

When *fetch* resolves, it modifies *myposts*, which triggers a *fetch* because it is listed as dependency of useEffect, which modifies *myposts*, and so it continues...

It seems that *myposts* depends on the result of the fetch, not the other way around. So I would suggest removing *myposts* from the dependency list.

Comment: Now I understand why it is causing infinite loop.. but is there any other way to re-render the component when a new post is uploaded? Would like to know the approaches please.

Comment: Because *myposts* is part of the state of the component, whenever *myposts* is modified, the component is re-rendered automatically.

Answer (score 1):

The useEffect hook is called when `myposts` gets updated. In the final `.then` of your fetch, you're updating it via `setPosts`. The best way to fix this is by making the dependency array an empty array.
But this won't solve the issue of updating posts from the server, but this can also be done in a periodic function with `setInterval`. This would result in something like the code below.

```js
const [myposts, setPosts] = useState([]);

const update = fetch('/mypost', {
  headers: {
    cookie: 'access_key',
  },
})
.then((res) => res.json())
.then((data) => {
  // console.log(data);
  setPosts(data.myposts);
});

useEffect(() => {
  update()
  const interval = setInterval(update, 30000)
  return () => clearInterval(interval)
}, []);
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I will try your solution but just wanted to know.. are their any other alternatives too?

Comment: There are a few alternatives to get updates from the server. The above approach is based on polling (letting the client check every so often), but you could also look into [Server-sent events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events) or [websockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket). There are some libraries that make it easier to use these technologies, but at their core, they all use one (or multiple) of these three techniques

Comment: Thanks a lot! will check those out :)